# What happened when I call UserTransaction.begin()?

Tags: java, transactions, distribution, jta

Let's say I have a code like this:

```java
public class Test{
    DataSource ds1;
    DataSource ds2;
    DataSource ds3;
    UserTransaction userTransaction;
    ...
    public void test(){
        userTransaction.begin();
        ds1.getConnection().createStatement().execute(...);
        ds2.getConnection().createStatement().execute(...);
        userTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

How does the UserTransaction knows about which DataSource I'm gonna use?

Cause it doesn't previously register DataSource into UserTransaction.

In my mind, the JTA is based on XA transaction. Which works like this:

```java
XADataSource xaDataSource1;
XADataSource xaDataSource2;

XAResource xaResource1 = xaDataSource1.getXAResource();
XAResource xaResource2 = xaDataSource2.getXAResource();

Xid xid = ...

xaResource1.start(xid);
xaResource2.start(xid);

xaDataSource1.getXAConnection().getConnection().createStatement().execute(...);
xaDataSource2.getXAConnection().getConnection().createStatement().execute(...);

xaResource1.commit(xid,...);
xaResource2.commit(xid,...);
```

So, does JTA's userTransaction.begin() call xaResource.start(xid) for all its managed DataSource?

Or how does it implement this mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

In a container environment, all transactional resources (your XAResources) must be previously enlisted as such by the application. This enlisment allows inform the participating resource manager when a transaction is started and to performa actual commit steps.

Provided that enlistment, as stated on JTA specification (https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=907):

> For each resource in use by the application, the application server invokes the enlistResource method and specifies the XAResource object that identifies the resource in use.
>
> The enlistResource request results in the transaction manager informing the resource manager to start associating the transaction with the work performed through the corresponding resource - by invoking the XAResource.start method. The transaction manager is responsible for passing the appropriate flag in its XAResource.start method call to the resource manager. (...)

The transaction id is associated with the current thread, per spec, when started by user (UserTransaction) or by the container. More than that, the implementation may coordinate communications with another remote transaction services so all of then are associated with the same transaction.

So, answering your questions, UserTransaction knows about the resources because they should be previously registered and controlled by the container. I think the specific implementation may be more or less broad - *v.g.*, a CDI container may associate only the injected resources of a transaction managed bean with its transaction, and not all other XAResources available to the application, or may register all of them for completeness.

Comment: But I only previously registered the XADataSource to the container. Did the container intercept the xaDataSource.getXAConnection().getXAResource() and register the XAResource to the container or what?

Comment: Simply answering, yes, it does that as defined on item 3.3.1 of [JTA spec](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=907). The application server is responsible for enlist em delist the resources, basically calling the method you referred as soon as it identify that a registered resource is XA capable and is linked to an application (or EJB, or CDI bean) that uses the given resource in a transaction.

Comment: Thx for your replying, That helps a lot